# How to implement model binder for ASP.NET Core 1 to trim form input spaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I want to trim the spaces from the form inputs. I realized that this is possible through custom model binder. I want to do that for ASP.NET Core 1.0 MVC6. I found and example http://www.hotzblog.com/asp-net-vnext-defaultmodelbinder-and-automatic-viewmodel-string-trim/ but it is for release candidate.

Please, can you help with giving me an example how to implement such model binder.

Answer (score 0):

As the author of that article, I would like to tell you that it has been now updated to support ASP.NET core 1.0.